# How to draw on a view?

Tags: c++, qt, model-view

There is a model, containing strings, and a list view.

The `QListView` is a descendant of `QPaintDevice`, so you can override `paintEvent (QPaintEvent *)` in it and draw something on it. For example, you need to draw image *cheker.png*:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QPaintEvent>
#include <QListView>
#include <QStringListModel>

class View :public QListView {
public:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event) {
        QListView::paintEvent(event);
        QPainter painter(this);
        painter.drawPixmap(10,10,QPixmap("cheker.png"));         
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QStringListModel model;
    QStringList list;
    list << "a" << "b" << "c" << "d" << "e" << "f" << "g" << "h";
    model.setStringList(list);

    View view;
    view.setModel(&model);
    view.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

checker.png looks like this:
[image]

What is expected is not happening - the picture does not show. The view is depicted as if no methods were overridden. And the following is printed in the console:

[image]

Actual results:

[image]

What I expect:

[image]

So, how to draw in a view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All item views that inherit from [`QAbstractScrollArea`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html) are a bit tricky in the sense that the list view itself is not typically the widget that is painted on. A view deriving from [`QAbstractScrollArea`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html) will have a viewport widget that is usually painted on instead. See: [`QAbstractScrollArea::viewport()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#viewport).

To draw the image, you can change the `paintEvent()` implementation to draw on the viewport widget by letting the painter take the viewport widget as the paint device. The following will draw a red line over the items in the list view:

```
void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event) override
{
  QListView::paintEvent(event);

  QPainter painter(viewport());
  painter.setPen(Qt::red);
  painter.drawLine(0, 0, 100, 100);
}
```

It will also get rid of the error messages you see on the console.

Answer (score 0):

`QListView::paintEvent()` reimplements `QAbstractScrollArea::paintEvent()` and documentation for the latter says:

> **Note:** If you open a painter, make sure to open it on the *viewport()*.

(Emphasis on viewport is mine.)

See Qt docs for [QAbstractScrollArea::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#paintEvent).